# Camunda - Filter Tasklist according to the assigned group

Tags: java, authorization, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I’ve created a user who belongs to a group called *Security*. In the [Camunda modeler](https://camunda.com/products/#product-modeler) I’ve explicitly assigned a task to a group *Facility*. However, on running the application,  I can see that the user who belongs to the group *Security* can see and claim a task which was assigned to the group *Facility*.

**How do I make sure that a Tasklist only displays the task which was assigned to a particular group of users?** The goal is that user can come and see the tasks of another group.

Comment: Can you please provide some code of what you have done so far?

Comment: Even a screenshot of your BPMN-diagram would already help...

Comment: Also: Welcome to SO! For more guidance on asking well-received questions, please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. The solution is, we need to create a filter to displays only tasks assigned to a specific user group.

For reference: [Here's the complete answer.](https://forum.camunda.org/t/filter-tasklist-according-to-the-assigned-group/20044/2)